dbt 1.8 unit_tests throwing node not found error
I've been trying my first unit_tests in dbt1.8 but, its throwing me compilation error saying "test depends on a node named xyz which was not found
in macro ref (macros/path/ref.sql)". Please any suggestions are appreciated.
what I have done so far,

verified xyz exists in my dbt_project
tried souce instead of ref in the below test input
fixtures directory structure is properly defined
tried the test with other formats like dict and sql but got same compilation error

here is my .yml file with unit_tests
version: 2

unit_tests:
  - name: test_state
    description: "check state"
    model: location
    given:
      - input: ref('details')
        format: csv
        fixture: mock_details
      - input: ref('all_details')
        format: csv
        fixture: mock_all_details
      - input: ref('all_values')
        format: csv
        fixture: mock_all_values
    expect:
      format: csv
      fixture: mock_state_comparison

